# Error on using git mergetool with opendiff after Mavericks and Xcode 5.0.1

Tags: git, mergetool, opendiff

I just install OS X Maverics and Xcode 5.0.1 but now when I'm trying to use `git mergetool` with `opendiff` I'm getting this error:

```
Normal merge conflict for 'Assets/Scripts/Characters/MobAI.cs':
{local}: modified file
{remote}: modified file
Hit return to start merge resolution tool (opendiff): 
2013-11-01 11:51:11.980 opendiff[1706:1007] too few arguments
2013-11-01 11:51:11.985 opendiff[1706:1007] usage: opendiff file1 file2 [-ancestor ancestorFile] [-merge mergeFile]
```

The `xcode-select` path is */Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/*

Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

This was my situation:

```
git config -l
```

(abbreviated output)

```
merge.tool=opendiff
mergetool.opendiff.cmd=/usr/bin/opendiff $2 $5 -merge $1
```

How I fixed it:

```
git config --global --unset mergetool.opendiff.cmd
```

Comment: Your answers will always be more helpful (and get more votes) if you include some explanation of the why and how (if you can). ;)